# Ideas for improving my Sudoku game

Tags: web-app, games

I am looking for ideas to improve my Sudoku game in cool ways,

http://www.sudokubum.com/

Comment: I have been talking about this exact issue in Stackoverflow from the programmable aspect, and got wonderful reviews, and on this site my question is been closed. this is a UX site, and people can learn from the UI of web games so they could implement some of it on their. I am sad my question got closed.

Comment: The problem is you didn't ask a question. You basically just said, "Check out my site, what do you think?" which is almost indistinguishable from spam. I'm sure that would be instantly closed on Stack Overflow as well. I'm guessing you asked questions on how to solve specific coding problems on Stack Overflow. If there's some particular facet of the user experience that you're trying to improve, we'd love to help you here as well. Please give it some thought and consider asking another question.

Comment: I looked through your questions over att stackoverflow. I only found one question about sudoku. It differs greatly from this one. It is a question that is specific. Don't you see the difference?

Comment: ok so I guess I thought this website is also about improving UX, like in the general sense of it. I will just go and ask this at Forrst then..

Comment: @vsync You can ask questions about UX here, you just have to specify what you're asking. Read [Gorilla vs Shark on the SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) for more about why that helps both you and us.

Answer (score 1):

Great touch with the keyboard support, although you should be consistent and disallow keyboard numbers that can't be in that cell just like you do with the mouse approach. To not confuse the player ("why isn't the keyboard working?") you could show the number pressed in red and fade it out.

Also, you could make the number selector slightly larger for mouse selection.

Something I find useful in Sudoko games is annotations, like marking possible numbers without filling in the square (make them small in the corner or greyed out).

For some inspiration on a multiplayer Sudoko game, check out http://www.sudokuandfriends.com/

Comment: yes you can do annotations...try it :)